# Numeros pares del 1 al 100 en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola tengo que ejecutar un script en workbench que muestre la lista de los números pares del 1 al 100 pero el codigo que utilizo no funciona, directamente no me reconoce la variable declare
necesito ayuda

[image: Script utilizado]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> La sintaxis de `dbms_output.put_line` pertenece a [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABEHIEG) y no así a MySQL.

Con un bucle `while` quedaría de este modo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pares()
BEGIN
  DECLARE numero INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE numero < 100 DO
    SET numero = numero + 2;
    SELECT numero;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

- Dentro de un procedimiento almacenado declaramos una variable que será usada para comparar por cada iteración si el número que se obtiene es menor o igual a 100.
- El bucle `while` hace uso de `SET` para hacer lo que en un lenguaje de programación sería: `numero = numero + 2`
- Hacemos uso de `SELECT` para que el procedure pueda imprimir en pantalla una vez que sea invocado el número resultante por cada iteración.
- Cerramos el bucle *while*
- Mandamos llamar al PA con: `CALL pares();`

**Enlaces de interés**

- [Enlace al ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6a9150e8c849259b8ce1433c272a5a5a)
- [Bucle while MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html)

Comment: Wow ahora tengo una gran base para seguir con los demás scripts te lo agradezco

Comment: de nada @Zeldars en la respuesta te dejé enlaces de interés al respecto considera revisarlos.

Answer (score 2):

Si estás usando **Mysql 8.0** o **MariaDB 10.2** o superiores, siguiendo [ESTA REFERENCIA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204513), puedes hacer

```
WITH RECURSIVE nums AS (
    SELECT 2 AS NUM1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NUM1 + 2 AS NUM1
    FROM nums
    WHERE nums.NUM1 <= 100
)
SELECT *
FROM nums;
```

Si estás usando **MariaDB 10** o superior, se han introducido [SECUENCIAS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/)

```
SELECT seq AS NUM1 FROM `seq_2_to_100_step_2`;
```

Comment: Para el caso de la secuencia en MariaDB, creo que se podría acortar aún mas dejándola así: SELECT seq AS NUM1 FROM `seq_2_to_100_step_2`;

Comment: Funciona correctamente con esta sintaxis, Las 2 respuestas fueron muy útiles, gracias

Comment: Si, es correcto @Aprendiz. No se especifica, pero puse la operación del cálculo par por si el caso es académico. Aunque mejor editaré la respuesta para que la referencia quede como la mejor práctica.